# JavaFX CSS in Eclipse - Why am I getting "Unknown Property" Warning?

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I've reviewed all the existing posts about this issue I could find. Most say to ensure JavaFX SDK is in the build path. I have put it in both the Modulepath and the Classpath, neither resolved the issue.

The CSS still works, but besides the yellow warning, it also will not auto-complete so learning more about he library is extra difficult.

I would prefer to get it working correctly so I have the auto-complete help to learn this library, not just to suppress the warnings.

[Warning in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsD0f.png)

[Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z05Sh.png)

Comment: why do you have the fx both on the module path and the classpath? they must be on the module path, nowhere else

Comment: @kleopatra I've tried every combo I could think of with no success. I did move everything to module path now. Still getting the warnings. (Will update image of Build Path)

Comment: Based on previous questions related to this, my assumption is that JavaFX support is subpar in Eclipse (and other IDEs, really). Desktop development, at least in Java, is not the big market—web and mobile development is. This means JavaFX tooling does not get as much attention as one might hope. Unfortunately, you may have to simply suffer through the warnings and lack of autocomplete. While probably not as easy to learn from, you can always reference the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) as needed.

Comment: it's still doubling .. fx sdk and javafx14 - whatever is below those choose exactly one (the one containing the jars)

Comment: did you fix the problem?